# Simple code neither working on jsfiddle nor codepen, but running on my browser (Chrome)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to make a simple mouse movement recorder using pure javascript. This recorder is perfectly working on my browser (Chrome) but not working either on jsfiddle, or codepen.io, and not even properly in stackoverflow's console. I am not aware of any compatibility issues with such programs.

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById("start");
button1.addEventListener("click", startOrPlay);
var button2 = document.getElementById("stop");
button2.addEventListener("click", stopOrAgain);
var pointer = document.getElementById("pointer");
var title = document.getElementById("title");
title.textContent = "Start Recording";
var recording = [];
var index = 0,
  length = 0,
  r;

function record(e) {
  recording[index] = [];
  recording[index][0] = e.clientX;
  recording[index][1] = e.clientY;
  index++;
}

function play() {
  pointer.style.top = recording[index][1];
  pointer.style.left = recording[index][0];
  index++;
  if (index == length) {
    clearInterval(r);
  }
}

function startOrPlay() {
  if (button1.textContent === "START") {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", record);
    button1.removeEventListener("click", startOrPlay);
    title.textContent = "Recording your mouse positions...";
  } else {
    index = 0;
    pointer.style.display = "initial";
    pointer.style.top = recording[index][1];
    pointer.style.left = recording[index][0];
    r = setInterval(play, 10);
  }
}

function stopOrAgain() {
  if (button2.textContent === "STOP") {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", record);
    length = index;
    index = 0;
    document.querySelector("#start p").textContent = "PLAY";
    document.querySelector("#stop p").textContent = "AGAIN";
    button1.addEventListener("click", startOrPlay);
    title.textContent = "Recorded";
  } else {
    index = 0;
    length = 0;
    recording = [];
    title.textContent = "Start Recording";
    pointer.style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("#start p").textContent = "START";
    document.querySelector("#stop p").textContent = "STOP";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
#start,
#stop {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
}
div p {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 6px;
}
#start:hover,
#stop:hover {
  background-color: cyan;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#start {
  top: 300px;
  left: 200px;
}
#stop {
  top: 300px;
  left: 1000px;
}
#pointer {
  display: none;
  width: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#pointer img {
  width: 100%;
}
#title {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
#instructions {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
#instructions:hover {
  height: 220px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="instructions">Instructions
    <br>1) This app will
    <br>track and record
    <br>you mouse's position
    <br>from the time of
    <br>clicking start to
    <br>clicking stop.
    <br>2) Use Full Screen
    <br>Window
    <br>3) Close any console.
    <br>4) Keep mouse inside
    <br>window</div>
  <div id="title"></div>
  <div id="start">
    <p>START</p>
  </div>
  <div id="stop">
    <p>STOP</p>
  </div>
  <div id="pointer">
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/90px/svg_to_png/222076/Mouse-Cursor-Arow-Fixed.png"></img>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The SO console gives an error, `"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined"` on `pointer.style.top = recording[index][1];`. I'm sure fixing it can prove to be useful.

Comment: Tried to fix that, found the bug, still the error message is not going. Now the program is also running smoothly on internet explorer. Still not on codepen/jsfiddle/SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a more detailed look at your code, and here are my notes:

1. An `<img>`-tag is self-closing, meaning there's no need for `</img>`.
2. Depending on how/where it's run, `button1.textContent` returns a 13-character string ("START" with newlines/whitespace) rather than just "START" as you expect, which is what triggered the SO/jsFiddle error. The fix is simple, you add `.trim()`: `if (button1.textContent.trim() === "START") {`.
3. You use button1.textContent for your conditions, but you never change its value. Same thing for button2, so your code can never stop/play, only record.
4. You remove the event listeners the first time they're called, how do you expect the 2nd branch of your if conditionals to be ran?
5. You never update your variable `length`, it stays 0 forever. Your play function loops over indexes that don't exist as it has no upper limit.
6. You were editing the pointer's style (e.g. `pointer.style.top`) but you were forgetting to add `+ 'px'` at the end of the style changes.

[Here's a working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2cu43zqy/) with your record/play. Simply click **START** to record, then click the same button (which is now **PLAY**) to play the record.

I haven't touched the `stop()` method, you can work that one out yourself. And to be fair, there is a lot more that can be improved in your code, but I'll leave it up to you to put some effort in googling JS style rules and best practices. Purchasing a good book is also a good idea.

Comment: I didnt realise there were so many problems, if only you could help me with the 2nd issue, on `console.log(button1.textContent.length)`, it shows me 5, so I dont understand the 13 character string. Also, I may have a conceptual misunderstanding, in the 3rd issue, doesnt `document.querySelector("#start p").textContent = "PLAY";` change `button1.textContent` automatically?

Comment: Issue #2 is because textContent includes whitespace. Since HTML often has extra newlines and tabs/spaces for readability, these get included. If it only happens on jsFiddle/SO, my guess is their script engines reformat or tidy up the code, which adds the whitespace. `.trim()` solves that problem. And you're right about issue #3, I just didn't take a real look at your stop code since I was first trying to make START/PLAY work and I ended up reworking some of the structure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it's running in your chrome because the code snippet you posted doesn't run on mine either. But I'll tell you what the issue is.

Issue is in your `startOrPlay()` func, you are doing an exact compare `button1.textContent === "START"` this fails because from your code you can see you have some new lines + a paragraph tag, if you `console.log(button1.textContent)` you'll whitespace is included in the "textContent" therefore your code jumps to the else which `recording[index][1]` will be undefined.

Anyways you can either use `trim()` or `indexOf` whichever will work.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/e8xLx0y2/) where `.trim()` is used.

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is not part of the answer but `<img>` tags are self-closing and don't need an extra closing `</img>` tag.

Comment: I might be having a conceptual misunderstanding, but in my browser, `console.log(button1.textContent)` is showing "START" and `console.log(button1.textContent.length)` is showing "5". Can you please help me out?